# How to get the return code of a spawned program

Tags: c++, linux, process

This will run a program and give me the return code.

```
int returnCode;

returnCode = system(program);
```

How can I do the same thing with execv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exec` family of calls trash the current process and launch the new program within the same process space. If you want to execute another program within your current program, you need to spawn a new process using `fork` You then call `exec` in the child process and get the parent to wait until the child process completes. The `waitpid` function will then provide the child process's return code.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Creation-Example.html#Process-Creation-Example) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv)

> The exec() family of functions
>   replaces the current process image
>   with a new process image.

ie, exec doesn't return.  What do you want to achieve, or put otherwise, what's wrong with system?

Comment: Clues to the answer to your question can be found in the OP's recent questions. For example, `setrlimit()`.